# Como obter informações de arquivos .torrent?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso obter informações de um arquivo *.torrent* usando alguma dessas classes:

- [**Torrent RW**](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/24765.html)
- [**Torrent-parse**](https://github.com/BotLife/torrent-parse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para exibir as informações de um arquivo *torrent* com a [classe `Torrent-RW`](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/24765.html), faça o seguinte:

```php
require "Torrent.php";

$torrent = new Torrent('ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent');
echo '<pre>Privado? ', $torrent->is_private() ? 'Sim' : 'Não',
     '<br>Anúncio: ';
var_dump($torrent->announce());
echo '<br>Arquivo: ', $torrent->name(),
     '<br>Comentário: ', $torrent->comment(),
     '<br>Tamanho em pedaços: ', $torrent->piece_length(),
     '<br>Tamanho: ', $torrent->size(2),
     '<br>HASH: ', $torrent->hash_info(),
     '<br>Status: ';
var_dump($torrent->scrape());
```

O resultado será algo assim:

```all
Privado? Não
Anúncio: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(39) "http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce"
  }
}

Arquivo: ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso
Comentário: Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com
Tamanho em pedaços: 524288
Tamanho: 1.11 Go
HASH: 1619ecc9373c3639f4ee3e261638f29b33a6cbd6
Status: array(2) {
  ["http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/scrape"]=>
  string(29) "Tracker request timeout (30s)"
  ["http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/scrape"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["complete"]=>
    int(1609)
    ["downloaded"]=>
    int(29)
    ["incomplete"]=>
    int(72)
    ["name"]=>
    string(29) "ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Aqui está](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M2dQn.png) uma *print* de como ele deveria funcionar.

Comment: Estranho, com seu arquivo, funcionou bem, aparece tudo, mas com os meus não funcionam.

Comment: @LucasCarezia Teste com outros arquivos, pode ser que esse arquivo *.torrent* que você usa para testar esteja corrompido ou algo assim.

Comment: Tentei com uns 7/8 arquivos e todos dão o mesmo poblema